# Why does Ethereum require use of UDP (and not TCP) for discovery?

Tags: security, connections, discovery-protocol

I am aware of the advantages of UDP, but why not allow a choice? Since since Tor requires the use of TCP, why have Ethereum developers elected not to support TCP for discovery?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

UDP-based discovery is one of the main paradigms of peer discovery.

For example, Universal Plug and Play ([UPnP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Plug_and_Play)) uses the UDP-based Simple Service Discovery Protocol ([SSDP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_Service_Discovery_Protocol)), and BitTorrent has a UDP-based [Local Peer Discovery](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_Peer_Discovery) protocol.

The general method is to multicast (broadcast?) over UDP and see who responds. The fact that UDP is [unreliable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reliability_(computer_networking)) - i.e. in short, it doesn't care about responses, in contrast to TCP - means it's not waiting around for responses from peers that don't exist, or which had previously existed but which are no longer online.

---

If we poke around a little closer in Ethereum's [RPLx specification](https://github.com/ethereum/devp2p/blob/master/rlpx.md) - where "*RLPx is a cryptographic peer-to-peer network and protocol suite*" - we see that Ethereum's [node discovery](https://github.com/ethereum/devp2p/blob/master/rlpx.md#node-discovery) is based on [Kademlia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kademlia), "*a distributed hash table for decentralized peer-to-peer computer networks*", which... uses UDP.